# Modify table dynamically in dbSet

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am using EF Core 3.0 and have a requirement to change table name dynamically for which I am thinking to create an extensiion method.

Exact requirement:
I have two tables 'Sample' & 'Sample_History' and I want to acheive somthing like this:

To get records from 'Sample' table: `DbContext.Samples.ToList();`
To get records from 'Sample_History' table: `DbContext.Samples.AsHistory().ToList();`

Here, i want to dynamically change name of table from 'Sample' to 'Sample_History' using extension method 'AsHistory'. The obvious way is to get the SQL and change it which i want to aviod. Is there some way I can change entity in dbSet itself?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your requirement correct then you can try this:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static DbSet<SampleHistory> AsHistory(this DbSet<Sample> sample)
    {
        return sample.GetService<DatabaseContext>().SampleHistory;
    }
}
```

And for make your extension method generic:

```
public static class DbSetExtensions
{
    public static DbSet<T> ToDbSet<T>(DbSet<Sample> dbSet) where T : class
    {
        return dbSet.GetService<DatabaseContext>().Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want extension method to be generic. Any idea how to do that?